# Arduino GPS Time And Coordinates Values Update Issue

Tags: arduino, gps, adafruit, gps-time

I'm new to arduino. There is an issue in the code I wrote in my project. The issue is when GPS sensor(Adafruit ultimate gps breakout v3) finds a satellite, GPS time and coordinates values not changing. Other values are working but only GPS isnt. (You can see the output and the code below.)

```
#include <Adafruit_GPS.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "DFRobot_BNO055.h"
#include "Wire.h"
#include <SFE_BMP180.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(51, 50);
Adafruit_GPS GPS(&mySerial);
typedef DFRobot_BNO055_IIC BNO;
BNO bno(&Wire, 0x28);
SFE_BMP180 pressure;
double baseline; // baseline pressure

#define GPSECHO true
#define ALTITUDE 820 // Altitude of My Home, in meters

void printLastOperateStatus(BNO::eStatus_t eStatus);
double getPressure();

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    bno.reset();
    while (bno.begin() != BNO::eStatusOK)
    {
        Serial.println("bno begin faild");
        printLastOperateStatus(bno.lastOperateStatus);
        delay(500);
    }
    Serial.println("bno begin success");
    delay(500);

    GPS.begin(9600);
    GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCGGA);
    GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_UPDATE_1HZ);
    GPS.sendCommand(PGCMD_ANTENNA);

    if (pressure.begin())
        Serial.println("BMP180 init success");
    else
    {
        // Oops, something went wrong, this is usually a connection problem,
        // see the comments at the top of this sketch for the proper connections.

        Serial.println("BMP180 init fail\n\n");
        while (1)
            ; // Pause forever.
    }

    delay(1000);
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(15, OUTPUT);

    // Get the baseline pressure:

    baseline = getPressure();

    Serial.print("baseline pressure: ");
    Serial.print(baseline);
    Serial.println(" mb");
}

uint32_t timer = millis();
void loop()
{
    char status;
    double T, P, p0, a, Pv;
    char c = GPS.read();
    BNO::sEulAnalog_t sEul;
    sEul = bno.getEul();
    if ((c) && (GPSECHO))



    // if a sentence is received, we can check the checksum, parse it...
    if (GPS.newNMEAreceived())
    {

        if (!GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA()))
            return;
    }
    if (millis() - timer > 2000)
    {
        timer = millis(); // reset the timer
        Serial.print("<");
        Serial.print("TeamID");
        Serial.print(">");
        //Saati if gpsfix in bi üstüne koy

        Serial.print("<");
        Serial.print(sEul.pitch, 3);
        Serial.print(">");
        Serial.print("<");
        Serial.print(sEul.roll, 3);
        Serial.print(">");
        Serial.print("<");
        Serial.print(sEul.head, 3);
        Serial.print(">");
        if (GPS.fix)
        {
        Serial.print("<");
        Serial.print(GPS.hour+3, DEC); 
        Serial.print(':');
        if (GPS.minute < 10) 
        {
            Serial.print('0');
        }
        Serial.print(GPS.minute, DEC);
        Serial.print(':');
        if (GPS.seconds < 10)
        {
            Serial.print('0');
        }
        Serial.print(GPS.seconds, DEC);
        Serial.print(">");
          //buraya
            Serial.print("<");
            Serial.print(GPS.latitudeDegrees, 6);
            Serial.print(">");
            Serial.print("<");
            Serial.print(GPS.longitudeDegrees, 6);
            Serial.print(">");
        }
   // Get a new pressure reading:
    Pv = getPressure();

    // Show the relative altitude difference between
    // the new reading and the baseline reading:
    a = pressure.altitude(Pv, baseline);


        //bmp180
        status = pressure.startTemperature();
        if (status != 0)
        {
            // Wait for the measurement to complete:
            delay(status);

            // Retrieve the completed temperature measurement:
            // Note that the measurement is stored in the variable T.
            // Function returns 1 if successful, 0 if failure.

            status = pressure.getTemperature(T);
            if (status != 0)
            {
                // Print out the measurement:
                Serial.print("<");
                Serial.print(T, 2);
                Serial.print(">");

                status = pressure.startPressure(3);
                if (status != 0)
                {
                    // Wait for the measurement to complete:
                    delay(status);

                    // Retrieve the completed pressure measurement:
                    // Note that the measurement is stored in the variable P.
                    // Note also that the function requires the previous temperature measurement (T).
                    // (If temperature is stable, you can do one temperature measurement for a number of pressure measurements.)
                    // Function returns 1 if successful, 0 if failure.

                    status = pressure.getPressure(P, T);
                    if (status != 0)
                    {
                        // Print out the measurement:
                        Serial.print("<");
                        Serial.print(P, 2);
                        Serial.print(">");

                        p0 = pressure.sealevel(P, ALTITUDE); // we're at 1655 meters (Boulder, CO)
                        Serial.print("<");
                        Serial.print(p0, 2);
                        Serial.print(">");


                        // On the other hand, if you want to determine your altitude from the pressure reading,
                        // use the altitude function along with a baseline pressure (sea-level or other).
                        // Parameters: P = absolute pressure in mb, p0 = baseline pressure in mb.
                        // Result: a = altitude in m.

                    }
                    else
                        Serial.println("error retrieving pressure measurement\n");
                }
                else
                    Serial.println("error starting pressure measurement\n");
            }
            else
                Serial.println("error retrieving temperature measurement\n");
        }
        else
            Serial.println("error starting temperature measurement\n");


        Serial.print("<");
        Serial.print(a,1);
        Serial.print(">");

        Serial.println();
    }
}
void printLastOperateStatus(BNO::eStatus_t eStatus)
{
    switch (eStatus)
    {
    case BNO::eStatusOK:
        Serial.println("everything ok");
        break;
    case BNO::eStatusErr:
        Serial.println("unknow error");
        break;
    case BNO::eStatusErrDeviceNotDetect:
        Serial.println("device not detected");
        break;
    case BNO::eStatusErrDeviceReadyTimeOut:
        Serial.println("device ready time out");
        break;
    case BNO::eStatusErrDeviceStatus:
        Serial.println("device internal status error");
        break;
    default:
        Serial.println("unknow status");
        break;
    }
}

double getPressure()
{
  char status;
  double T,P,p0,a;

  // You must first get a temperature measurement to perform a pressure reading.

  // Start a temperature measurement:
  // If request is successful, the number of ms to wait is returned.
  // If request is unsuccessful, 0 is returned.

  status = pressure.startTemperature();
  if (status != 0)
  {
    // Wait for the measurement to complete:

    delay(status);

    // Retrieve the completed temperature measurement:
    // Note that the measurement is stored in the variable T.
    // Use '&T' to provide the address of T to the function.
    // Function returns 1 if successful, 0 if failure.

    status = pressure.getTemperature(T);
    if (status != 0)
    {
      // Start a pressure measurement:
      // The parameter is the oversampling setting, from 0 to 3 (highest res, longest wait).
      // If request is successful, the number of ms to wait is returned.
      // If request is unsuccessful, 0 is returned.

      status = pressure.startPressure(3);
      if (status != 0)
      {
        // Wait for the measurement to complete:
        delay(status);

        // Retrieve the completed pressure measurement:
        // Note that the measurement is stored in the variable P.
        // Use '&P' to provide the address of P.
        // Note also that the function requires the previous temperature measurement (T).
        // (If temperature is stable, you can do one temperature measurement for a number of pressure measurements.)
        // Function returns 1 if successful, 0 if failure.

        status = pressure.getPressure(P,T);
        if (status != 0)
        {
          return(P);
        }
        else Serial.println("error retrieving pressure measurement\n");
      }
      else Serial.println("error starting pressure measurement\n");
    }
    else Serial.println("error retrieving temperature measurement\n");
  }
  else Serial.println("error starting temperature measurement\n");
}
```

Output:

```
<TeamID><17:07:58><0.500><62.562><279.312><39.980690><32.662307><27.37><885.40><976.68><304.3>
<TeamID><17:07:58><0.500><62.562><279.312><39.980690><32.662307><27.48><885.44><976.72><305.1>
<TeamID><17:07:58><0.500><62.562><279.312><39.980690><32.662307><27.62><885.65><976.95><303.5>
<TeamID><17:07:58><0.500><62.500><279.312><39.980690><32.662307><27.71><885.61><976.91><304.7>
<TeamID><17:07:58><0.500><62.437><279.312><39.980690><32.662307><27.79><885.60><976.89><303.8>
<TeamID><17:07:58><0.500><62.437><279.250><39.980690><32.662307><27.76><885.65><976.95><302.6>
<TeamID><17:07:58><0.375><62.437><279.187><39.980690><32.662307><27.68><885.61><976.91><302.7>
<TeamID><17:07:58><0.375><62.437><279.187><39.980690><32.662307><27.80><885.65><976.96><303.3>
```

[OutputPicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilxxE.png)

Comment: Are you testing it in an open environment? For the coordinates to update, you have to guarantee that you get at least 3 satellites.

Comment: Yep i tested it. I didn't understand why.